# Custom deserializer or different class design Retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, deserialization, retrofit

Retrofit makes things so easy for a noob like me.  However, the API response structure that I'm requesting for my current project doesn't follow the same format as I have used before.  I am unsure of whether I need to rewrite my POJO or make a custom deserializer in GSON.  I cannot change the JSON structure and a custom deserializer seems daunting to me.

Here is the JSON:

```
        {
    "Green Shirt": [
        {
            "id": "740",
            "name": “Nice Green Shirt",
            "quantity": "0",
            "make": "",
            "model": "",
            "price": “15.00",
            "size": "XXS",
            "sku": null,
            "image": "https:\/\/google.com\/green_shirt.jpg",
            "new_record": false,
            "category_name": "",
            "bar_code": "",
        },
        {
            "id": "743",
            "name": "Green Shirt",
            "quantity": “68",
            "make": "",
            "model": "",
            "price": “20.00",
            "size": "XS",
            "sku": null,
            "image": "https:\/\/google.com\/green_shirt.jpg",
            "new_record": false,
            "category_name": "",
            "bar_code": "",
        }
    ],
    "Dark Blue Jeans": [
        {
            "id": "1588",
            "name": "Dark Blue Jeans",
            "quantity": "0",
            "make": "",
            "model": "",
            "price": "0.00",
            "size": “S",
            "sku": null,
            "image": "https:\/\/google.com\/dark_blue_jeans.jpg",
            "new_record": false,
            "category_name": "",
            "bar_code": "",
            "category": null
        },
        {
            "id": "1559",
            "name": "Dark Blue Jeans",
            "quantity": "4",
            "make": "",
            "model": "",
            "price": "0.00",
            "size": “XL",
            "sku": null,
            "image": "https:\/\/google.com\/dark_blue_jeans.jpg",
            "new_record": false,
            "category_name": "",
            "bar_code": "",
            "category": null
        }
    ],
    "White Belt": [
        {
            "id": "1536",
            "name": "White Belt",
            "quantity": "37",
            "make": "",
            "model": "",
            "price": "0.00",
            "size": "One Size",
            "sku": null,
            "image": "https:\/\/google.com\/white_belt.jpg",
            "new_record": false,
            "category_name": "",
            "bar_code": "",
            "category": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the POJO:

```
    public class Product
{
    private String model;

    private String bar_code;

    private String image;

    private null sku;

    private String new_record;

    private String size;

    private String id;

    private null category;

    private String price;

    private String category_name;

    private String name;

    private String quantity;

    private String make;

    public String getModel ()
    {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel (String model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getBar_code ()
    {
        return bar_code;
    }

    public void setBar_code (String bar_code)
    {
        this.bar_code = bar_code;
    }

    public String getImage ()
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage (String image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public null getSku ()
    {
        return sku;
    }

    public void setSku (null sku)
    {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public String getNew_record ()
    {
        return new_record;
    }

    public void setNew_record (String new_record)
    {
        this.new_record = new_record;
    }

    public String getSize ()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize (String size)
    {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public null getCategory ()
    {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory (null category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPrice ()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice (String price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCategory_name ()
    {
        return category_name;
    }

    public void setCategory_name (String category_name)
    {
        this.category_name = category_name;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getQuantity ()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity (String quantity)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getMake ()
    {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake (String make)
    {
        this.make = make;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [model = "+model+", bar_code = "+bar_code+", image = "+image+", sku = "+sku+", new_record = "+new_record+", size = "+size+", id = "+id+", category = "+category+", price = "+price+", category_name = "+category_name+", name = "+name+", quantity = "+quantity+", make = "+make+"]";
    }
}
```

Here is the request and Retrofit interface:

```
    public static void requestData(String username,String password) {

        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT);

        if (username != null && password != null) {
            // concatenate username and password with colon for authentication
            final String credentials = username + ":" + password;

            builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    // create Base64 encodet string
                    String string = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", string);
                }
            });
        }
        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();


        ProductAPI api = adapter.create(ProductAPI.class);

        api.getInventory(new Callback<List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Product> products, Response response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.getUrl());
                Log.d(TAG, response.getReason());
                mInventory = product;
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d(TAG,error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

public interface ProductAPI {
    @GET("/v2/get-inventory")
    public void getInventory(Callback<List<Product>> response);
}
```

This is the error I get because the JSON starts with '{' instead of '['
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I told Retrofit (GSON?) to look for a `Map<String,List<Product>>` instead of just a `List<Product>` and it figured it out, how convenient.
:

```
        api.getInventory(new Callback<Map<String,List<Product>>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Map<String,List<Product>> products, Response response) {

                mInventory = products;
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d(TAG,error.getMessage());
            }
        });

public interface ProductAPI {
    @GET("/v2/get-inventory")
    public void getInventory(Callback<Map<String,List<Product>>> response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems exactly what it says. The response is an object that has an array and not an array directly:

```
{ [{},{},{}] }
```

If the response was:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

It would work, but as you cannot change the response format you should change your java. Instead of expecting a List of Products you should have an object that has a List of Products inside. That is how retrofit will map it.

Edit:
The response is actually as follows:

```
 {[],[],[]}
```

Is not a list, is an object composed with three Lists of Objects Product

The mapping to an object will have to be:

```
public class Wrapper
{
   List<Product> WhiteBelt;
   List<Product> DarkBlueJeans;
   List<Product> GreenShirt;

}
```

Something like that would be your structure. I dont believe is right, because you usally want a list and not an object with three lists inside "hardcoded".

Let me know if it helps

Edited:

So you need somthing like this:

```
{
    "products":
     [{ "name" : "Green Shirt"
        "items":
         [{"id": "740",
           "name": “Nice Green Shirt",
           "quantity": "0",
           "make": "",
           "model": "",
           "price": “15.00",
           "size": "XXS",
           "sku": null,
           "image": "https:\/\/google.com\/green_shirt.jpg",
           "new_record": false,
           "category_name": "",
           "bar_code": ""
         }]
      }]
}
```

That would be a structure that accepts a list of Products and inside each prodcut you have the list of items (the one you already have).

In Java:

```
public class ProductList
{
    List <ProductList> productList;
}

public class ProductList
{
    String name;
    List<Product> items;
}
```

Using your original Product class

Comment: The list isn't getting populated within my new object what's wrong with: `public class Inventory {
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
    private List<Product> products;
}`

Comment: So I did the "hardcode" solution and it did populate all the lists and objects within them, so that was huge progress for me.  I do need a solution that takes any number of lists of products because the real structure is way too enormous to hardcode and that's what makes me think I have to get down to the GSON and figure out how to make my own custom deserializer.  Thanks alot for your help, I'd give you an upvote but I don't even have 15 rep yet.

Comment: I really wish the API would give a different response structure but changing it is beyond my control.  I don't think I can convince anyone to change it anytime soon.  I appreciate all the help though man.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, try formatting it properly first before doing anything else.

**Properly formatted:**

```
{
  "Green Shirt": [
    {
      "id": "740",
      "name": "Nice Green Shirt",
      "quantity": "0",
      "make": "",
      "model": "",
      "price": "15.00",
      "size": "XXS",
      "sku": null,
      "image": "https:\\/\\/google.com\\/green_shirt.jpg",
      "new_record": false,
      "category_name": "",
      "bar_code": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "743",
      "name": "Green Shirt",
      "quantity": "68",
      "make": "",
      "model": "",
      "price": "20.00",
      "size": "XS",
      "sku": null,
      "image": "https:\\/\\/google.com\\/green_shirt.jpg",
      "new_record": false,
      "category_name": "",
      "bar_code": ""
    }
  ],
  "Dark Blue Jeans": [
    {
      "id": "1588",
      "name": "Dark Blue Jeans",
      "quantity": "0",
      "make": "",
      "model": "",
      "price": "0.00",
      "size": "S",
      "sku": null,
      "image": "https:\\/\\/google.com\\/dark_blue_jeans.jpg",
      "new_record": false,
      "category_name": "",
      "bar_code": "",
      "category": null
    },
    {
      "id": "1559",
      "name": "Dark Blue Jeans",
      "quantity": "4",
      "make": "",
      "model": "",
      "price": "0.00",
      "size": "XL",
      "sku": null,
      "image": "https:\\/\\/google.com\\/dark_blue_jeans.jpg",
      "new_record": false,
      "category_name": "",
      "bar_code": "",
      "category": null
    }
  ],
  "White Belt": [
    {
      "id": "1536",
      "name": "White Belt",
      "quantity": "37",
      "make": "",
      "model": "",
      "price": "0.00",
      "size": "One Size",
      "sku": null,
      "image": "https:\\/\\/google.com\\/white_belt.jpg",
      "new_record": false,
      "category_name": "",
      "bar_code": "",
      "category": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Some of the errors it had:

```
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 12]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 28]
Error:Invalid comma, expecting }.[Code 141, Structure 53]
Error:Expecting string, not }.[Code 8, Structure 54]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 67]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 79]
Error:Invalid comma, expecting }.[Code 141, Structure 104]
Error:Expecting string, not }.[Code 8, Structure 105]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 138]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 192]
```